# read file path android studio

Tags: java, android, weka

hi im still newbie on android programming. i'd like to know how to read a file path like "/home/emulator/0/blabla/file.txt/" in android code. i need to know how to read a file path because i have to access specific files on android from an app that i'll make. and the path is already defined on the code so the user will only get the output of the reading.

```
public void naivebayes() throws Exception {
        //im using weka to read a .arff file
        //the problem is i didnt know how to "write" the path, from where i should start it
         //p.s: i already tried open the files on my phone then clikc "Details" to see the path on the             phone and write it on the code but the code still could'nt read the files
        DataSource source = new DataSource("File Path");

        Instances dataset = source.getDataSet();
        //set class index to the last Attributes
        dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);
        //create and build the classifier
        NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
        nb.buildClassifier(dataset);
        tv.setText(nb.getCapabilities().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use hard coded file paths. The framework will give you the base path of the area you want to save files to.

For the SD card, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

For local files, use `Context.getFilesDir()` (or `Context.openFileOutput(String name, int mode)`, etc)

For local cache, use `Context.getCacheDir()`

Comment: so basically, i have to place my files on the emulator?